# SBT: adding the resolvers of a sbt project to those of the project depending on it

Tags: dependencies, sbt, dependency-resolver

I have a SBT project `A` published at `../nexus-url/.../a`

I have another SBT project `B` which depends on `A` and in order to acquire it, it adds `../nexus-url/.../a` to its list of resolvers. project `B` is published to `../nexus-url/.../b`

I have another SBT project `C` which depends on `B` and so in order to acquire it, it adds `../nexus-url/.../b` to its list of resolvers.

Now, problem is that project `C` fails to add `B` as a dependency because it doesn't manage to find project `A`. I would have imagined that when importing `B`, it would look for its dependencies in `B`'s resolvers, but that doesn't seem to be happening. Was I wrong to expect this?

If yes, Is there a way of embeding the `B`'s dependency information in the published package so that A can happily come along and import it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add all the resolvers you depend upon. So in your case, for project C, you need to add both `../a` and `../b` to your list of resolvers.